# What is the best way to queue AWS Step Function executions?

Tags: node.js, express, ethereum, aws-step-functions

I am triggering a step function through an Express route in a Node app. This step function interacts with the Ethereum blockchain, and is thus highly asynchronous. There is also a possibility of transactions failing if a multiple attempts are made at once.

As such, I want to queue up executions of this step function, but oddly there doesn't seem a straightforward way to do so.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: More detail on this might help to come up with better approach but with the information that you have provided, one way is to go via SQS to Step Function to achieve queue up the execution.

Comment: @223seneca, checkout my answer and let me if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with **Map in Step Functions**.

Step Functions provide **inbuilt way** execute in parallel or on execution at a time for given number of items. Below is an example:

```
"Validate-All": {
  "Type": "Map",
  "InputPath": "$.detail",
  "ItemsPath": "$.shipped",
  "MaxConcurrency": 0,
  "Iterator": {
    "StartAt": "Validate",
    "States": {
      "Validate": {
        "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:ship-val",
        "End": true
      }
    }
  },
  "ResultPath": "$.detail.shipped",
  "End": true
}
```

You need to change the value of **MaxConcurrency=1** so that only one execution will happen once and it will keep going until your items in **InputPath** is completely not exhausted. **InputPath** is supposed to be a `list`, you can queue up your items in **InputPath** and start the State Machine.

You can read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html).

Comment: If this works, it is a very elegant way to approach this! It’s the weekend now and I probably can’t hop back on this until Monday, but I promise I’ll accept this once I get a chance to try it out and it works.

Comment: @223seneca Sure, keep us updating.

Comment: Upon further reflection, I'm not sure this will work, because it lacks the ability to queue step function _executions_ as opposed to elements of an array passed an input to the single step function execution. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @223seneca would you mind having a chat about it or else you can try it out and we can discuss after that.